# Edição de pergunta mal elaborada

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica, edição

A pergunta em questão é [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59580/converter-tipo-de-data-no-mysql), que logo de imediato eu fiquei sem entender qual a dúvida. Depois de ler umas 3 vezes e ainda com a pergunta do usuário *rray* sobre PHP (o que aparentemente não havia nenhuma relação) eu resolvi dar uma olhada nas [revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/59580/revisions) e notei que a edição feita alterou de forma considerável o entendimento da pergunta.

Bom, o editor já possui os privilégios necessários para a edição ser feita imediatamente, sem passar por análise. Queria mesmo debater se só pra mim que a edição feita deixou a pergunta pouco clara, tendo que abrir as revisões para poder compreender. Alguma ação pode ser tomada?

Comment: Podes reverter ou sinalizar a um moderador. Mas cuidado com as reversões, se se tornarem uma guerra é melhor sinalizar mesmo e deixar quieto.

Comment: E não acho que tenha sido assim tão alterada... Quer dizer ele não fala em PHP na pergunta. Falta ai alguns esclarecimentos por parte do AP.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi que o editor quis deixar a questão mais objetiva, e de fato o autor estava dando voltas. Mas um dos pontos é que a edição tirou qualquer relação de resposta com o PHP, que foi o ponto central da pergunta.

Comment: O php era uma tag, se chamar date('c'); essa data sai no mesmo formato da pergunta

Comment: @rray esse é o ponto. Depois que foi retirado tanto a tag quanto na pergunta, eu e talvez outros não saberiam que ele queria a resposta para PHP. De qualquer forma, essa suas resposta é melhor que a minha, coloca lá ;)

Comment: Eu li algumas vezes a pergunta também não entendi o que ele queria, se gravar do php para o mysql ou formatar do mysql para o php. Pelo que procurei o mysql não grava diferentes times zones em uma coluna, por padrão é UTC ou outro definido arbitrariamente. Para pergunta ficar boa, precisa de uma confirmação do autor se para ele o timezone faz diferença ou não.

Comment: De fato eu editei a pergunta, pois o autor deu muitas voltas, mas editei principalmente por essa frase: `Como faço para mostrar uma data nesse formato tendo um campo timestamp ou date no mysql?`, que começa com `Como faço` e termina com `no mysql`. Então entendi que não tinha nada a ver com PHP, pois o usuário também não colocou nenhum código PHP. Peço desculpas, serei mais cuidadoso nas próximas vezes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu reverti a edição. Acredito que a intenção do editor tenha sido boa, mas o resultado não foi. De fato foram removidas informações importantes, e a pergunta acabou ficando mais confusa.